# How do I hide the address bar on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, url, webview

I open WebSet like this:

```
-(void)open
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://183.82.0.221:4321/Member/ReserveDeal?DealID=28"]];
}
```

It's showing like this:

[image]

How do I hide the address bar?

First if it's possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

### First:

***No***. The code you're using will open the URL in the browser, which is outside of your app. You don't directly control the browser on the device. Rather, the URL is sent to the system which then responds by opening it in the browser.

### Secondly:

If you want to show external HTML content from within your app and don't want to provide an address bar, use a [UIWebView, like shown in the documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/index.html)